# how to check if a message has a ping in it discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know you can use:

```
client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if(msg.content.includes("<@") && msg.content.includes(">")){
        //some code
    }
})
```

but this method isn't really the best. Is there a better way to check for pings in a discord message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if there are any mentions in a message, you can just get the mentions in the message and check the size of them by using:

```js
if (message.mentions.users.size !== 0) {}
```

You can then replace the `.users` with `.channels` to check if there were any mentioned channels and `.roles` to check if any role was mentioned

Comment: You can also use `if (message.mentions.users.size)`

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `message.mentions.members.first()` to get the first pinged user.
So, using your example:

```
if(message.mentions.members.first()){
    //some code
}
```

Comment: I was gonna need a way to get the pinged user as well, Thanks!